# Upon Remote-ssh the setup waits on the file vscode-scp-done.flag . the tar file is present and so are the locks but waiting never seems to end

Tags: ssh

The tar file is present and so are the locks but waiting never seems to end on the subject file. Thank you. I am doing this using visual Studio Code and Extension Remote-ssh

Comment: You might want to redirect this question to superuser or stackexchange for more traffic.

Comment: Hey Jody, did you solve this?